# Set "Project Owner" and "Project Due Date" using API

Tags: asana

Does anyone know if there's a way to set the "Project Owner" and "Project Due Date" attributes of an Asana project using the api (https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't yet rolled out support for the new project sidebar data (things like owner, due date, project status, red/yellow/green status). There is a not-yet-officially supported "owner" field you can specifically request using `opt_fields` if you're in a rush, though.

Comment: Any way to fetch the project-level due dates right now?

Comment: Not currently, no, sorry :-(

Comment: @agnoster any plans to include project-level due dates in the api?